# css-How to place text and button on an image grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a CSS grid layout with 5 images that looks like below:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is below:

[image]

However, I am using CSS grid and wondering if I could achieve this without using margin?

My code:

```
 <!--CSS Grid to display home page images -->
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class=" bed"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" alt="">
    
    </div>
    <div class="pillow"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Pillow.jpg')}}" alt=""></div>
    <div class=" kitchen"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Kitchen.jpg')}}" alt=""></div>
    <div class=" living-room"><img src="{{asset('/images/Shop_Page.jpg')}}" alt=""></div>
    <div class=" sofa"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Sofa.jpg')}}" alt=""></div>




</div>

@endsection

@push('style')
<style>

@media (max-width: 700px) {

.bed {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1 / -3;
}
.pillow {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}



.kitchen {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}



.living-room {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}



.sofa {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
}

}



.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  padding: 5em;
  grid-gap: 2.5em;
  background-color: black;
  
  height: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.bed {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  height: 110%;
  width:100%;
}


.pillow {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 110%;
  width:90%;
}



.kitchen {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}



.living-room {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}



.sofa {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
}



img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


body{
    background-color: black;
    }


.container {
  position: relative;
 
}


    .heading-part {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .main-title {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        float: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .main-title::after {
        border-bottom: 3px solid #552244;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: -3px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
</style>
@endpush
```

I need the text and button to be bottom of each image and the font size should be different since each image are of different resolution. Is there a way to implement this elegantly without making my code look like a mess?

Is there any way I can implement this according to the size of the image elegantly?

Edit:

This is how it looks on mobile

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text in your mockups looks like it go someplace when clicked, so it's therefore a link, not a button. Each `.wrapper > div` is already relatively positioned, giving making it a bounding container for any absolutely positioned children. Therefore, you can add a link to the `.wrapper > div` and pin it to the bottom corner of each grid cell.

All you would need to add is the following. You would then style to your liking:

```css
.wrapper>div>a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And then the `HTML`:

```html
<div class=" bed">
  <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" alt="">
  <a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a>
</div>
```

```css
.bed {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1 / -3;
}

.pillow {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.kitchen {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}

.living-room {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}

.sofa {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 2fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  padding: 5em;
  grid-gap: 2.5em;
  background-color: black;
  height: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper>div {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>div>a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrapper>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.bed {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  height: 110%;
  width: 100%;
}


.pillow {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  height: 110%;
  width: 90%;
}



.kitchen {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}



.living-room {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / -1;
}



.sofa {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row: 5 / -1;
}



img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}


body {
  background-color: black;
}


.container {
  position: relative;

}


.heading-part {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-title::after {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #552244;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class=" bed">
    <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" alt="">
    <a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="pillow"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Pillow.jpg')}}" alt=""><a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a></div>
  <div class=" kitchen"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Kitchen.jpg')}}" alt=""><a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a></div>
  <div class=" living-room"><img src="{{asset('/images/Shop_Page.jpg')}}" alt=""><a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a></div>
  <div class=" sofa"><img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Sofa.jpg')}}" alt=""><a href="#">Label <span class="">➡</span></a></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5mtvzpq/)

Comment: Thanks, does that mean only the arrow button is clickable?

Comment: @LordJesus No, the whole string and the arrow are clickable.

Comment: Oh you mean the HTML I have to add inside the div of each img?

Comment: @LordJesus Yes. Updated the answer for you.

Comment: Can you have a look at my updated post? It seems that in mobile layout, with media query, the images looks weird even if they fit together.

Comment: @LordJesus This is not the typical way to post. Create a new post since all the answers here relate to the old (original) question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hope this will work...
```

HTML-

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bed">
        <span>[your text here]&nbsp;<button>[button]</button></span>
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Bed.jpg')}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="pillow">
        <span>[your text here]&nbsp;<button>[button]</button></span>
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Pillow.jpg')}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="kitchen">
        <span>[your text here]&nbsp;<button>[button]</button></span>
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Kitchen.jpg')}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="living-room">
        <span>[your text here]&nbsp;<button>[button]</button></span>
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Shop_Page.jpg')}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="sofa">
        <span>[your text here]&nbsp;<button>[button]</button></span>
        <img src="{{asset('/images/Home_Sofa.jpg')}}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.wrapper > div {
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper div span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Your `HTML` is not semantic. This is not how to use a `label`.